# Combobox not showing groupings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to organize the items in a combobox into groups. To do this I've created an object that has project and group name strings. I then set the GroupStyle and ItemTemplate to display these values. However, Currently, only the project string is displayed in the combobox (and the box has a red border, indicating some kind of error).

Here's the xaml for my combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxProjects" Margin="165,90,28,0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxDefault}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectClientSelections.ProjectGroupItems,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectClientSelections.SelectedProject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 

    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Project}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

</ComboBox>
```

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GroupStyle`, the DataContext is not your item (the type contained in your ItemsSource), but a `CollectionViewGroup` object, which is formed based on the collection of items that you have grouped. Because of this you have to declare a binding path to one of the properties in CollectionViewGroup, for example, based on your code you probably want to use `Name` property. See [MSDN CollectionViewGroup Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx)

Change your `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate` to this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

You don't show how you have formed your GroupDescriptions. If you have not grouped the items already, you can do it in following way (assuming the XAML you have provided is contained inside Window and Window's and GroupBox's DataContext is the same):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        Source="{Binding ProjectClientSelections.ProjectGroupItems}"
        x:Key="GroupedProjectItems">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription
                PropertyName="GroupName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

After this change `GroupBox` `ItemSource` binding to the following (directly to  `CollectionViewSource` resource):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedProjectItems}}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!